# Phase and group velocity of a soliton?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, waves, solitons, phase-velocity

How do I find the phase velocity and group velocity of a [soliton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) with a $\operatorname{sech}$ (hyperbolic secant) envelope?